# Is it possible to have Media Center show details for my movie files?

Tags: windows-media-center

I just switched to the Windows 7 media center for TV and generally love the interface but the Movie tab won't pull movie data like it would in xbmc or another alternate.

Is there a way of getting media center to pull title/poster/cast info for an avi file like it would for a DVD?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I manage the [Media Browser](http://www.mediabrowser.tv) project.

It works on Windows 7, gives you coverflow, poster view, themes, detail view, deep metadata search capabilities, filtering, advanced sorting, TV metadata (from thetvdb.com), Movie metadata (from themoviedb.org), ITunes trailer, DVR-MS metadata, podcast support and more.

Comment: Wow. That's an amazing project.  I had it installed and working in seconds.  It can only get better from here.

Comment: That's the one I use too, weirdly couldn't find the link for it yesterday

Answer (score 2):

There are loads of Addons that do this kind of thing, this is one

http://www.collectorz.com/movie/windows-media-center-mce.php

More addons here

http://thegreenbutton.com/forums/thread/20347.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I've been using [MyMovies](http://www.mymovies.name) to do that - it's good for both on the shelf dvds and downloaded movies (include auto import of information from amazon/imdb ...)

Answer (score 0):

There are much simpler ways to do this with add ons and other extra software, but the way it is intended to be done can be quite time consuming if you already have a large movie collection built in the Windows Media Center Library.

Every File has properties and in the file that you're movies in their are spaces for you to input data, (ie) Director, producer, year, synopsis. This will carry over and organize in WMC after you have opened your library, it make take a few minutes.

For cover art it is very simple but also time consuming, each movie file should be in its own subfolder within the folder you're collection is derived from, and in that folder a .jpg file should be inserted under the name "folder" (Lowercase) This .jpg will serve as the cover photo.

Windows assumes that users input this data naturally however that normally isn't the case.